# Binary combinations count

Tags: binary, combinations, combinatorics

How can we find out the total count of combinations with number of continuous 0s <= 4 in n-bit binary numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Let `T(n)` be the number of numbers of binary length n that you are interested in. Then it should be that there is a recursive linear formula `T(n)=2*T(n-1)-T(n-6)` that can be solved using standard techniques and identifying the base case(s), where what you are looking for is `T(16)`.

```
T(i)=2^i up to i < 5
T(5)=2^5 - 1
T(n)=2*T(n-1)-T(n-6) for n > 5
```

Solving the recurrence yields a formula that should be fairly simple and should be evaluated fast for many values of n.

The reasoning behind the recursive formula is that adding 1 is always safe which accounts for `T(n-1)` term. Then there is another term `T(n-1) - T(n-6)`, which reflects the fact that we cannot extend numbers of length n-1 with 0 if their suffix consists of 4 zeros in which case the last but 5th digit must be 1 that extends any "good" number with n-6 digits.

Comment: Perhaps, solving the recurrence exactly would lead to irrational numbers that cannot be expressed in terms of roots, but just applying the recursion should be also reasonably fast.

Comment: Very nice approach! However, it misses some cases, e.g. for n=6, this formula gives T(6) = 60, when the valid combinations are 61 (only 000000, 000001, 100000 are not valid).

Comment: I think there was an index shifted n - 5 should go to n - 6. Now, for T(6)=2*(32 - 1) - 1 = 2*31 - 1 = 62 - 1 = 61

Comment: Yes! I had in mind that T(n) =  Σ(T(m)) from m=n-5 to n-1, but it results in your formula.

Comment: Yes, they are pentanacci numbers https://oeis.org/A001591 as I just learned. Thanks for pointing this out!